# NWConnection, 100% CPU usage and crash after sending 512 UDP packets

Tags: ios, swift, performance, udp

This is my first time writing Swift and using Xcode, so please bear with me.

I'm trying to write an iPhone app which takes values from the device's gyroscope/magnetometer and sends them in UDP packets to a specific IP address and port, at a specific rate (1-100Hz). This way, I can strap my phone to my head and use it as 'free' TrackIR alternative.

[Opentrack](https://github.com/opentrack/opentrack), the software I'm using to receive the UDP packets, expects 48 bytes. 6 8-byte doubles in this order: X, Y, Z, Yaw, Pitch, Roll. Since I can't measure the phone's position relative to the display, the first 3 doubles will be 0. While Yaw, Pitch and Roll will be the phone's attitude in degrees.

Here's a stripped down version of my code so far ([full file here](https://pastebin.com/HXznw1fm)):

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion
import Network

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var enabled = false
    var rate: Int = 100
    var motion = CMMotionManager()
    var connection: NWConnection?

    @IBOutlet weak var activeState: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ipAddress: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var port: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var rateDisplay: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rateSlider: UISlider!
    
    func radToDegData(value: Double) -> Data {
        return withUnsafeBytes(of: value*180/Double.pi) { Data($0) }
    }
    
    func startStream(hostUDP: NWEndpoint.Host, portUDP: NWEndpoint.Port) {
        motion.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1 / Double(rate)
        motion.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!){ (data, error) in
            if let trueData = data{
                let UDPmessage = self.radToDegData(value: 0) + self.radToDegData(value: 0) + self.radToDegData(value: 0) + self.radToDegData(value: trueData.attitude.yaw) + self.radToDegData(value: trueData.attitude.pitch) + self.radToDegData(value: trueData.attitude.roll)
                self.connection = NWConnection(host: hostUDP, port: portUDP, using: .udp)
                self.sendUDP(UDPmessage)
                self.connection?.start(queue: .global())
            }
        }
    }
    
    func stopStream() {
        motion.stopDeviceMotionUpdates()
    }
    
    func sendUDP(_ content: Data) {
        self.connection?.send(content: content, completion: NWConnection.SendCompletion.contentProcessed(({ (NWError) in
            if (NWError == nil) {
                //print("Data was sent to UDP")
            } else {
                //print("ERROR! Error when data (Type: Data) sending. NWError: \n \(NWError!)")
            }
        })))
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    @IBAction func enableSwitch(_ sender: Any) {
        enabled.toggle()
        if enabled {
            startStream(hostUDP: .init(ipAddress.text!), portUDP: NWEndpoint.Port(rawValue: UInt16(port.text ?? "4242")!) ?? NWEndpoint.Port.any)
        } else {
            stopStream()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having 2 problems:

- Running this on a physical iPhone SE 2 at 100Hz, Xcode reports 100-101% CPU usage. I can't really imagine that this app is that demanding, even at 100Hz. Another odd thing is that while I'd expect 100% usage to mean that the speed is throttled down, I'm still receiving ~100 packets per second on [a Python script](https://pastebin.com/dBViGPWc) on my laptop I wrote for testing.
- No matter the rate, only 512 packets are sent. After that, 2 error messages are printed to the console for every attempt:

```
2020-12-13 22:03:44.765054+0100 UDPHeadTrack[5571:3061403] [] nw_path_evaluator_create_flow_inner NECP_CLIENT_ACTION_ADD_FLOW 31FA4B2D-1E8A-4D16-A1A6-D023471B59C0 [28: No space left on device]
2020-12-13 22:03:44.765089+0100 UDPHeadTrack[5571:3061403] [connection] nw_endpoint_flow_setup_channel [C513 192.168.0.1:4242 in_progress channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, ipv6, dns)] failed to request add nexus flow
```

Since this is my first Swift project, a good chunk of it is copy-pasted examples/documentation, which I'm assuming is why I'm experiencing these problems. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new `NWConnection` each time you receive a motion update.  Your app can only have a limited number of open network connections (512 in this case).  Once the quota is exceeded you get an error message.

A simple restructure is just to use an existing `NWConnection` if it exists:

```
func startStream(hostUDP: NWEndpoint.Host, portUDP: NWEndpoint.Port) {
    motion.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1 / Double(rate)
    motion.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!){ (data, error) in
        guard let trueData = data else {
            return
        }

        if self.connection == nil {
            self.connection = NWConnection(host: hostUDP, port: portUDP, using: .udp)
            self.connection?.start(queue: .global())
        }
        
        let udpMessage = self.radToDegData(value: 0) + self.radToDegData(value: 0) + self.radToDegData(value: 0) + self.radToDegData(value: trueData.attitude.yaw) + self.radToDegData(value: trueData.attitude.pitch) + self.radToDegData(value: trueData.attitude.roll)      
        self.sendUDP(udpMessage)
       
    }    
}

func stopStream() {
    motion.stopDeviceMotionUpdates()
    self.connection?.cancel()
    self.connection = nil

}

func sendUDP(_ content: Data) {
    guard let connection = self.connection else {
        return
    }
    connection.send(content: content, completion: NWConnection.SendCompletion.contentProcessed(({ (error) in
        if let error = error {
           print("ERROR! Error when data (Type: Data) sending. NWError: \n \(error)")
        } else { 
            print("Data was sent to UDP")
        }
    })))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now getting 6% CPU usage at 100Hz. Is there a way to get rid of the `completion` argument of the `connection.send()` function? Or will printing that string 100 times per sec make no difference in performance when not in a debugging session?

Comment: You don't have to do anything in the completion handler if you don't want to.  I wouldn't think that the prints would consume much CPU when not debugging

Comment: Came across a little issue. When starting the stream, then stopping, then changing ip address, then starting again, it still uses the first address. Would a good solution be to create a new connection every time, without checking `if self.connection == nil`. And to add `self.connection?.cancel()` at the bottom of the `stopStream()` function?

Comment: I mean like [this](https://pastebin.com/dtjeTCp5). It seems to be working but I'm not sure if I'm closing the connection correctly, i.e. if I will get errors after enabling/disabling the stream 512+ times.

Comment: In `stopStream` you should cancel the connection and then set it to `nil`. That way a new connection will be created when you start the stream.